# How to add Image in window default action bar in android?

Tags: android

I have window default action bar in which want to add Imageview with height and width 30x30.how can I do that, I am trying this code ,but can't see Imageview.

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(actionBar.getDisplayOptions() | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(actionBar.getThemedContext());
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.amazon);
    ActionBar.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(30, 30, Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    layoutParams.rightMargin = 40;
    imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    actionBar.setCustomView(imageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your

```
ActionBar.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(30, 30, Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
```

with

```
ActionBar.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(
        ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.RIGHT
                | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
```